# PHP time variable Conversion

Tags: php, date, time

am just developing a time tracker app and i need to calculate difference between two times..

i done the difference syntax like below

```
$d1 = date_create($start_time); 
$d2 = date_create($end_time); 
$diff = date_diff($d1, $d2); 
$elapsed_time= $diff->format("%h Hours and %i Minutes "); 
echo $elapsed_time;
```

the variables $start_time and $end_time are coming from database as a **"time"** type field..

the result showed in my browser like below..

```
2 Hours and 35 Minutes
```

the result is correct now.

now i want to insert the difference variable (**$elapsed_time**) into my database as a **time** type field namely **elapsed_time**

the query is used to insert is showed below.

```
$query="UPDATE task SET elapsed_time='$elapsed_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result1=mysql_query($query);
```

at that time the field like **00:00:02** this

what is the necessary steps to convert my **$elapsed_time** to get proper time value like **02:35:45**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format the time properly. It's only one extra line of code.

```
$elapsed_time= $diff->format("%h Hours and %i Minutes "); 
$elapsed_time_for_mysql = $diff->format("%H:%I:%S"); // MySQL time format


$query="UPDATE task SET elapsed_time='$elapsed_time_for_mysql' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
```